# Seeing "internal error: Huge input lookup [1]" error when trying to create a large powerpoint file using OFFICER package

Tags: officer

I don't have a great way to give a reproduceable example, but here's my best description. I'm running a loop that generates 60 different powerpoint slides, each in officer and creates a list, which results in a "pptx document with 60 slides" in my R environment. However, when I try to print this list, I see the following error:

**Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  :
internal error: Huge input lookup [1]**

I tried running the list with only 10 powerpoint slides, and the print works, creating a slide deck of 10 slides. But I guess 60 is beyond the level that is considered "huge." Is there a way to override this? I saw some other posts about how you can add a Huge override, but I'm not exactly sure where I would do that.

Comment: (note: I am the maintainer of the package) Yes, I agree, 60 slides is not huge. I think that's a limit of xml2 (the dependency/package in charge of manipulating the underlying XML) and the resources of your machine. How much RAM do your machine have? Also, what kind of content did you add in the slides?

Comment: Running 8GB of RAM here. From a content standpoint, I'm writing mostly gg objects (charts) and a few flextables. Pretty much all 60 of the files are between 500-600KB in size. Thanks for the note about the limit, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this xml2 manipulation.

Comment: Agree, I would like to see a solution!  I just tried to read in a kml that was like 0.01 GB and it couldn't do it...got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

`set options = c("HUGE")` for `read_xml()`